# Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[image]

How can I get the top 2 max values for a price change using pandas dataframe?

**Example:** row 1 to 4 shows negative trend of price & my expected result would be first two prices being the lowest. Similarly top 2 highest price for positive prices.

thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please do not post code in images, please copy and paste it into text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your values into groups, filter groups with only one value and keep only two (absolute) highest values.

```
grp = df['Price change'].lt(0).ne(df['Price change'].lt(0).shift()).cumsum()

idx = df.groupby(grp).filter(lambda x: (len(x) >= 2)) \
        .groupby(grp).apply(lambda x: abs(x['Price change']).sort_values().tail(2)) \
        .index.levels[1]

out = df.loc[idx]
```

```
>>> out
    Price change
0           -4.8
1           -3.8
6           -2.8
7           -3.8
12          13.2
13          15.2
14          -9.8
15          -8.8
```

**Update**

> How can I add this to the data frame as a last column (to the original table)?

```
df['Result'] = out['Price change'].reindex(df.index)
```

```
>>> df
    Price change  Result
0           -4.8    -4.8
1           -3.8    -3.8
2           -2.8     NaN
3           -1.8     NaN
4            3.2     NaN
5           -0.8     NaN
6           -2.8    -2.8
7           -3.8    -3.8
8            5.2     NaN
9            7.2     NaN
10           9.2     NaN
11          11.2     NaN
12          13.2    13.2
13          15.2    15.2
14          -9.8    -9.8
15          -8.8    -8.8
16          -7.8     NaN
17          -6.8     NaN
18          -5.8     NaN
19          -4.8     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are the star *, one last query how can I add this to the data frame as a last column (to the original table)